# Jquery for nested element

Tags: jquery

I have DIV structure as below (pls check the [image](http://share.pho.to/67R5I)). I wanted to change the content of the text box when i click on relative button using Jquery.

[image]

for example, if i click button (1), then content of textbox (1) should change. Similarly if i click button (2) then content of textbox (2) should change.

i have written the following code, but it is working for button(2), when i click button(1) it changes content of both textbox.

```
     $(document).on('click', '.b', function(e) {
        var a = $(this).closest('.a');
        $('.c', a).val("sample text");
    });
```

i can solve this by having different classes for different button / textbox. But i wanted to have the same class structure and solve the problem.

Comment: Instead of an image of your div structure, could you provide us this within a http://www.jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your DOM structure is always the same as in your image, this should work.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="a">
    <input type="text" class="c">
    <input type="button" value="Button" class="b">
    <div class="a">
        <input type="text" class="c">
        <input type="button" value="Button" class="b">
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.b').on('click', function () {
    //Find parent .a
    var $a = $(this).parent();

    //Add in the text
    $a.children(".c").val("sample text");
});
```

[**WORKING EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/umP3N/1/)

Comment: thank you for adding the HTML section as well. Actually textBox(1) and button(1) are below the inner DIV. Anyway it is working :). Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

It works that way because you traverse up to the closest `".a"` element and then perform a find, which is recursive in nature; this is why it will select both text boxes.

Instead, just find the sibling element:

```
$(document).on('click', '.b', function(e) {
    var $c = $(this).siblings('.c');
    $c.val("sample text");
});
```